# Finding whether the function in continuous in the origin of a function of 3 limits

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve this question about whether the function in continuous in the origin:

$$ f(x,y,z) = \frac{e^{y^2}\cdot cos(x+y-z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \quad \text{if}\quad  (x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0) \\ \text{and} \quad f(x,y,z)= 0 \quad \text{if} \quad (x,y,z) = (0,0,0) $$

I tried to break it down by approaching from the coordinate axis:

$$ \lim_{t_\to0} f(0,t,0) = \frac{e^{t^2}\cdot cos(t)}{t^2}$$

But when trying to solve it using Taylor i get that it approachs infinity, How can i do otherwise? Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. It appears that you successfully showed the function is discontinuous at the origin.

Comment: Do you think that's enough to show that its discontinuous at the origin? I'm new to the multivariable course so i'm not pretty sure if i did right!

Comment: You did it correctly. A single limit that fails is enough to show that it is discontinuous. Alternatively, had the limit been zero, that would not have been sufficient to show that the limit is actually zero.

Comment: Can i also conclude that the function is not differentiable at the origin since its discontinuous? I know that a differentiable function is continuous but not sure if the opposite is also true!

Comment: If a conditional statement is true, then its contrapositive is also true. so, you have "If a function is differentiable at a point, then it is continuous at that point." The contrapositive of that statement is, "If a function is not continuous at a point, then it is not differentiable at that point."